# Rails: Omniauth Facebook Permissions currently staggered - why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

When I initially register with my app via Omniauth, the popup dialog box says that Facebook will ask only for my public information. When I check the user in the rails console, the email field is "nil".

When I sign out and sign back in, it then says that Facebook would like my email and likes as well. My email address is now present in when running "rails c" in Terminal. I would like Facebook to ask users for these extended permissions on initial registration/signing-in, why is it currently staggered?

Here's the code for the Omniauth.rb initializer:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new { |env|
  OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint.new(env).redirect_to_failure
}

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret'],
       :scope => 'email,user_likes,user_location', :provider_ignores_state => true
end
```

And here's the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid, :email, :image)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still having this issue, but I was running into the same issue and solved it by changing the following code in my facebook.js.coffee file:

```
  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login ((response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse), scope: "publish_actions, publish_stream, photo_upload, manage_pages, video_upload"
```